# How to fix incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT

Tags: ruby, character-encoding

The issue is with the 'chap << "\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF"' line.

```
chaps = []
ctoc = "toc1\x00"
ctoc << [3, chapters.size].pack("CC")
chapters.each_with_index do |ch, i|
  num = i+1
  title = ch[:title]
  description = ch[:description]
  link = ch[:link]

  ctoc << "ch#{num}\x00"

  chap = "ch#{num}\x00"
  chap << [ch[:start]*1000, ch[:end]*1000].pack("NN");
  chap << "\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF"

  title_tag = [title.encode("utf-16")].pack("a*");
  chap << "TIT2"
  chap << [title_tag.size+1].pack("N")
  chap << "\x00\x00\x01"
  chap << title_tag

  chaps << chap
end
```

I have added the following to the top of the file but that didn't fix the issue. Any other ideas to try?

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

Comment: The issue is actually with the line above the line you mention, the `pack` is returning an ASCII-8BIT string and that is turning `chap` into an ASCII-8BIT string, and then you try pushing a UTF-8 string into it. I'm not that good with encodings, but you could try using `String#force_encoding` to convert the result of pack to UTF-8, though that changes a lot of characters from (for example) "\x03" to "\u0003", which may or may not be good enough (I admit a pretty thorough ignorance of character encodings and the underlying bytes and such); thought I'd at least point you to the right line though

Comment: If I comment out the pack("NN") it still fails but if comment out the "\xFF" line it passes. So are you sure?

Comment: huh commenting out the pack line lets the "\xFF" line works, for me, commenting out the "\xFF" line would work though because you don't do anything else with the string (in the sample you've shown), so it doesn't matter what encoding the string ended up with

Comment: I added more of the actual code. I only copied over a snippet to keep the problem short and clear. I appreciate your help. I'm trying to look into the encodings you're talking about. I do see it changing just have to figure out how to fix it

Comment: Thanks for your help I figured it out. I force_encoding("ASCII-8BIT") on the "\xFF| line.

Comment: glad you figured it out, my usual reflex is to try to get a string into utf-8 and just keep it there, didn't even think about just trying to go the other direction

Comment: @SimpleLime Do you know of a way to figure out what the following is "\x00\x00\x00'\x00\x00\x00"?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean "what the following is", you can always ask another question, about that though